# Flutterflow to Revenue Cat is not picking up and the button is not responding what is need to fix this?

Tags: flutter, revenuecat, flutterflow

When trying to enable subcriptions to the app the purchase button is not responding i belive it may not be able to communicate with Revenue-Cat I've followed the Docs provided by flutterflow/reveune-cat but am still not able to get this version released to the app store and it fails stating the button is not responsive. Below are the configurations on Flutterflow/Revenue-Cat.

Flutter Flow
[Flutterflow Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtQpH.png)

Rev-Cat

Product
[Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4bed.png)

Entitlement
[Entitlement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyYsQ.png)

Offering
[Offering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BEYE.png)

Below is the Appstoreconnect Configs.
[App Store Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9AHb.png)

The Apporiate API Keys have been added to both Rev-Cat and FlutterFlow

Confirm if the the configuration is correct and what may be missing and provide the right configs or any missing parts or a way to verify if the keys and the setting is correct